# Angular doesn't validating date type

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use input[date] in my form, but angularjs doesn't validate any date:

```
<form name="myForm">
    {{birthday}} <br/>
    <input type="date" ng-model="birthday" id="birthday" name="birthday"></input>
</form>
```

If I try to put "alex" inside the input, it accepts!

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3GKeM/2/ (please try with firefox)

Comment: `type="date"` is a HTML5 feature that must be supported by the browser. The above works fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: this example: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D also works fine in my firefox, but my programs doesn't works! I must to do something to it accepts html5?

Comment: sorry, I commented to soon. Was just reading that now...

Comment: @Dalorzo he's not asking "how" to do it. He's asking why this feature isn't working in Firefox. Which I answered below.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to use a new feature in AngularJS 1.3.x from AngularJS 1.0 which doesn't support `type="date"`.

If you want that support on FireFox. You'll have to use AngularJS. 1.3

The documentation you're referring to is for 1.3

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D

Comment: Yes, you're right, but how can I use I18N to change date format with angular 1.3? In previous versions, I just added angular-locale_pt-br.js.

Comment: Ah, that's a different question ;)

Comment: So, don't you know this answer? ;)

Comment: No clue. I haven't done any localizing with angular.

Comment: @AlexandreTRINDADE: Hi, I'm the author of that feature. Currently, it only supports ISO 8601 dates. This is for two reasons: 1. It's what the HTML5 spec dictates, and 2. There haven't been features implemented yet that will parse any localized date. I have a proposal and some concept work done, but nothing solid yet. For now you'd have to implement your own validator with something like Moment.js if you wanted to handle non-ISO dates.  A better idea would be to add a polyfill control date selector that would output ISO dates and bind to an input[type=date].  Best of luck.

Comment: @blesh Thank you so much for your explanation. I've developped an <h-field> directive that renders many kinds of inputs using css bootstrap. So, I will add my own custom date validation, based on $locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.mediumDate (ex: "dd/MM/yyyy" for english) and using ngModel.$formatters and ngModel.$parsers. What you think about that?

Comment: I think it's going to be a lot of work to create from scratch. You could save yourself a *lot* of headaches and unit testing and use something like Moment.js to parse the dates. Ultimately though, if you're sending these back to a server via Ajax, it's going to be advisable to send them back as ISO formatted dates (because that's generally the standard), so the best course of action, IMO, would be to use a date selection plugin that outputs ISO dates along with Angular 1.3.

Answer (score 1):

This behaves as expected in Firefox. [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime) reports that this HTML5 feature is not yet supported in Firefox 32 or earlier.

So you'll need to implement a javascript solution if you want all browsers to behave similarly. I'd suggest [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). It's used by a lot of people, has an alright look to it (which you can customize actually) and there are lots of examples on how to use it.

Other options:

- [Pickdate](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/)
- [Bootstrap Datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)
- [And the Angular UI Bootstrap option](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker)

**Update**

You stated that you already have your own datepicker (in comments below), and you are just looking for validation: you may want to consider looking at [HTML5 Patterns - Date](http://html5pattern.com/Dates). They have a variety of `Regex` solutions for validation. They have several different date formats already in place for you.

And then you can use Angular `ng-patter` to pass in the `regex`:

example:

```
<input type="text" ng-pattern="[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])"></input>
//accepts: YYYY-MM-DD
```

Comment: This is not an Angular solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I already have my own datepicker, I have this problem just when I'm affecting date values. So, I need to create my own validation to make this works, isn't?

Comment: @btm1 And `input type="date"` is also not an angular option. Angular is Javascript. Hence all of the examples I just gave are potential Angular Options. Granted, they aren't done as a directive, but that's just a matter of implementation.

Comment: @AlexandreTRINDADE, correct, you'd need to do your own validation. Probably just a simple directive that accepts a regex or something (guess it depends on the required date format, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I would either use ng-validate and a regex to check the format of the input value or because i do believe ng-validate has been deprecated depending on what version you're using, I would use ng-change on the input where you pass the model for the form to a function where you then check the format of the value and set the model to be invalid or valid. Here's a working example I've pulled from my app where i check to see if it is in fact a phone number and that it begins with 1.

```
checkNumber: function(number,form) {
            var num = parseInt(number.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, '')),
                l = num.toString().length,
                first = num.toString()[0];

            console.log(num);
            if(number && first != '1' || number && l < 11) {
                form.$setValidity('phoneNumber',false);
                form.phoneNumber.$setValidity('format',false);
            } else {
                form.$setValidity('phoneNumber',true);
                form.phoneNumber.$setValidity('format',true);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are browser inconsistencies as to what constitutes a valid date. A valid date string in firefox or ie, is invalid in chrome and vice-versa. I solved a similar issue by creating a custom validation directive that works quite nicely. you can find it here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/fortesl/2uv6xmjL/6/
Also shown below:

```
app.directive('dateFieldValidator', [function () {
var validateDate = function (date, format) {
    if (!date.length) {
        return true;
    }
    return moment(date, format.toUpperCase(), true).isValid();
};

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
        dateFormat: '@'
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

        //For DOM -> model validation
        ngModelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
            var valid = validateDate(value, scope.dateFormat);
            ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('validDate', valid);
            return valid ? value : undefined;
        });

        //For Model Update --> DOM
        ngModelCtrl.$formatters.unshift(function (value) {
            var valid = validateDate(value, scope.dateFormat);
            ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('validDate', valid);
            return value;
        });
    }
};
```

}]);